# App crashed when i run this app to use viewpager using fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin

I implement the swipe able viewpager using use the fragment and tab-layout , but when i run this project in the emulator then see, that my application was crashed and open the logcat and the see the this type of error.... what can i do please help me for that.

> 08-26 10:38:34.569 12296-12296/com.example.fragment_viewpager
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.fragment_viewpager, PID: 12296
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragment_viewpager/com.example.fragment_viewpager.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML
>   file line #9: Error inflating class 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>           at com.example.fragment_viewpager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:12)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>           at com.example.fragment_viewpager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:12) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>           at com.example.fragment_viewpager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:12) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 24: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x1d9
>   "res/color/secondary_text_material_light.xml" a=1 r=0x106011a}
>           at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:447)
>           at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:738)
>           at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:671)
>           at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:87)
>           at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:83)
>           at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:79)
>           at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.setTitle(Toolbar.java:755)
>           at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.(Toolbar.java:304)
>           at androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar.(Toolbar.java:229)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
>           at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
>           at com.example.fragment_viewpager.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:12) 
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: Please format the question properly and add your code.

Comment: Please add XML file also

Comment: seems your XML has an element which can't be inflated at line number 9 or something, "Binary XML file line #9: " so share your XML

Comment: ok i add the example file